# Why does jquery not see changes in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, dom

I make an Ajax request, after which I am change an attribute value. In the DOM, everything changes as expected. But when I click the button again, the old attribute value is displayed in the console. It seems that he does not see a change in the markup and loads old data.

```js
$('.more_credits_first').click(function () {
 var button = $(this)
 var show = $(button).data('show');
 console.log(show)

 if (show == 'show') {
  $.get(window.location.pathname,{}).done(function(data){
   $('.tbody.main_credits').append(data.template);
   $(button).attr('data-show', 'hide');
   $(button).text('Hide');
  })
 } else {
  $(this).attr('data-show', 'show');
  $(this).text('More');
 }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class='more_credits_first' type="button" data-show='show'>Button</button>
```

Comment: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://stacksnippets.net/js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` — The `done` function never gets called so `data-show` is never modified in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/):

> Since jQuery 1.4.3, data-* attributes are used to initialize jQuery data. An element's data-* attributes are retrieved the first time the data() method is invoked upon it, and then are no longer accessed or mutated (all values are stored internally by jQuery).

jQuery caches `data()`. You can use an attribute value to initialize it, but then jQuery will only look at its internal record.

Don't mix jQuery's `data()` API with `attr()`. Use `data()` to set the value as well.

Comment: That. And also make sure your request succeeds, as you have only `.done()` handler which does not run when network error occurs.

Comment: Very thnx for help.